# VIIRIS Nightlights resolution when merging raster files in R

Tags: raster, r, resolution

I do download Nightlights data from NASA (login neccessary, I`ve got the one for Germany tiles h18h19 v03 v04, four files in total) :

https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/archive/allData/5000/VNP46A4/2013/001

I get the bounding coordinates of my files from here: https://modis-land.gsfc.nasa.gov/pdf/sn_bound_10deg.txt

From the data description I can see: "NASA's Black Marble nighttime lights product, at
15 arc-second spatial resolution" (https://viirsland.gsfc.nasa.gov/PDF/BlackMarbleUserGuide_v1.2_20210421.pdf)

I would like to merge those 4 raster files to 1 by: `test <- do.call(raster::merge, files)`
What I have done so far:

```
#read files
filelist_temp <- list.files(".", full.names = TRUE)
files <- lapply(filelist_temp, function(x) {rast(x, "//HDFEOS/GRIDS/VIIRS_Grid_DNB_2d/Data_Fields/AllAngle_Composite_Snow_Free")})


#get the tile information of datasets
extent_extract <-  gsub(".*\\.(h\\d+v\\d+)\\..*", "\\1", filelist_temp)

#read extent bounding box text file
extent <- read.delim("C:/Users/apxxz/Desktop/NL/sn_bound_10deg.txt", skip = 5, sep = "")
#create an Tile id
extent <- extent %>% mutate(id= paste0("h",sprintf('%02d', as.numeric(ih)),"v",sprintf('%02d', as.numeric(iv))))

#keep those tile, which are needed
extentions <- extent %>% filter(id %in% extent_extract) %>% 
                dplyr::select(., 3:7)
#assign CRS
for(val in 1:4) {terra::crs(files[[val]]) <- "+proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371007.181 +b=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs"}
```

Until this step all of my files have the same resolution:

```
for(val in 1:4) {print(terra::res(files[[val]]))}
[1] 1 1
[1] 1 1
[1] 1 1
[1] 1 1
```

But when I´m adding the tile extention information by:

```
#assign extentions
for(val in 1:4) {terra::ext(files[[val]]) <- as.numeric(extentions[val,1:4])}
```

The x of my resolutions is different each time:

```
for(val in 1:4) {print(terra::res(files[[val]]))}
[1] 0.008340292 0.004166667
[1] 0.010191458 0.004166667
[1] 0.006487583 0.004166667
[1] 0.007530542 0.004166667
```

Running my pursued code I obtaining (obviously):

```
test <- do.call(raster::merge, files)
Error: [merge] resolution does not match
```

Are my "new" obtained resolutions correct, or could I just change them by `res(files[[]] <- c(1,1)`? If not, how could I merge those files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method for finding the extent seems fiddly and fraught with possible errors. The `h5` files actually have the lat-lon coordinates so you should maybe read those using the `ncdf4` package.

Bundled up into a function, something like this:

```
library(ncdf4) 
library(terra)

readh5 <- function(h5){

    r = terra::rast(h5,
             "//HDFEOS/GRIDS/VIIRS_Grid_DNB_2d/Data_Fields/AllAngle_Composite_Snow_Free")

    n = ncdf4::nc_open(h5)
    ## see these via `names(n$var)`
    lon = ncdf4::ncvar_get(n, "Data Fields/lon")
    lat = ncdf4::ncvar_get(n, "Data Fields/lat")

    ## assuming the coords are bottom left cell coords,
    ## add a cell width/height unit to the coords

    w = abs(mean(diff(lon)))
    h = abs(mean(diff(lat)))
    
    elon = range(lon) + c(0,w)
    elat = range(lat) + c(0,h)

    terra::ext(r) = c(elon, elat)
    terra::crs(r) = "epsg:4326"
    r
}
```

One point here I'm not sure of is the adjustment. The `terra` package's concept of "extent" goes to the outer edges of the cells. The data here is a 2400x2400 raster and 2400 longitude values and 2400 latitude values. Normally I'd assume they were cell centres, and add half a cell width/height to the extent to adjust. Somewhere in the docs it should tell you what the values are. I looked at another one where the coordinate starts at -180.000 which makes me think this has to be the *left* edge of a cell

```
> n = nc_open("./VNP46A4.A2013001.h00v03.001.2021119115411.h5")
> lon = ncdf4::ncvar_get(n, "Data Fields/lon")
> head(lon)
[1] -180.0000 -179.9958 -179.9917 -179.9875 -179.9833 -179.9792
```

...so my code above adjusts according to that assumption. Do check before using this for further analysis.

Warning delivered, this is how the function works:

```
r = readh5("./VNP46A4.A2013001.h19v04.001.2021119124741.h5")
# 64k is missing value/ocean or something
r[r==65535] <- NA
plot(r)
```

or nicely with:

```
# log trans for a bit more contrast:
library(tmap)
tmap_mode("view")
tm_shape(log(r))  + tm_raster()
```

[image]

which shows the registration is probably right. Note that:

```
> res(r)
[1] 0.004166667 0.004166667
> ext(r)
SpatExtent : 10, 19.9999999999994, 40.0041666666587, 50.0041666666667 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
>
```

Data read in like this should be compatible enough to be merged.